# $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$ is equivalent to $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$, where $W_i$ ($V_i$) is the space of row (column) vectors.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

$W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$ is equivalent to $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$, where $W_i$ ($V_i$) is the space of row (column) vectors.

How to show?

Precisely, if $A_1,A_2$ are two $m\times n$ matrices. Let $W_1,W_2$ be the space of row vectors of $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively;  $V_1,V_2$ be the space of column vectors of $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively. Show that $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$ is equivalent to $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$.

It sounds like $rank\left(A\atop B\right)=rank(A)+rank(B)$ if and only if $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$. But how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\text{dim}V_i=\text{dim}W_i\quad i=1,2$$
and for any two subspaces $V,W$
$$\text{dim}V+\text{dim}W-\text{dim}(V+W)=\text{dim}(V\cap W)$$

Comment: Then how? $rank\left(A\atop B\right)=rank(A B)$?

Comment: Then how? Could you please give some more hints?

Comment: Then how? More hints?